# Angular2 to Angular4 update (decrease code size in webpack)

Tags: angular, webpack-2

We have updated our web app from Angular 2.1.1 to 4.1.2, using Webpack 2 for building and development. Everything works fine. The code size in our produced build, however, has not decreased.

Do we need to configure [AoT compilation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) in our setup, in order to decrease the code or should the code be smaller right away? ([Angular's Webpack doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) does not mention AoT directly.)

Any hints to the key factors that impact the code size of an Angular 4 build in Webpack would be of great help.

Comment: [AoT is basically a no-brainer in production.](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/08/14/ahead-of-time-compilation-angular-offline-precompilation/)

Comment: a u on `angular-cli`?

Comment: https://blog.craftlab.hu/multiple-solutions-for-angular-ahead-of-time-aot-compilation-c474d9a0d508

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce payload size you need to produce an `AOT` build https://blog.nrwl.io/angular-is-aot-worth-it-8fa02eaf64d4 it will make you app performance better and should make the bundle size smaller as well as you no longer need to ship compiler and templates to the client browser. Also there is another thing that reducing the app bundle size is called [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

To get `AOT` build s very easy to achieve using [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) you just have to run a command like `ng build --prod` by doing that `angular-cli` is producing the `AOT` build and also runs [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) on it using [Rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup).

You do not have to use `angular-cli` to get `AOT` build, you just can configure
[@ngtools/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack) plugin with your webpack build.

Then once you done that you can inspect your bundles with this tools:

- https://github.com/th0r/webpack-bundle-analyzer
- https://github.com/danvk/source-map-explorer
- https://github.com/robertknight/webpack-bundle-size-analyzer

Personally I prefer `webpack-bundle-analyzer`. This way you can find all the waste in your bundles and then by tweaking your `code` like modifying `import statements`, etc, you can get rid of waste.

**UPDATE:**
There is a new experimental flag `--build-optimizer` introduced in cli(`ng build --prod --build-optimizer`) that can reduce the bundle size